# How do I send a server postback safely with PHP?

Tags: php, curl, postback, file-get-contents, webhooks

I'm building an application that will send an http request to a url (I hope..) provided by a user.

Probably most of you will know this as a postback, callback or webhook.

However, I'm concerned about security, because the other server will send a response. That response might contain code or who knows what.

I've considered the following functions so far:

- Curl()
- file_get_contents()

What is the most secure way of doing this, without opening up a security vulnerability?

Comment: What is the context? What is the 'response' from the request going to be used for?

Comment: @Landen we won't use the response for anything. We're mostly sending them data rather than the other way around. Although being able to know we received a 200 response might be slightly useful.

Comment: You won't have to worry about what the response is if you're not doing an eval or otherwise incorporating it into your code. All you're doing at this point is sending information one way. Using curl you can the read just the status code, but ignore the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You doesn't have a security problem in any case if you don't process the response of the server.

For example, when you use:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/testaddr';
$result = file_get_contents($url);
unset($result);
```

You have a variable with the data. But these data aren't processed yet.

With cURL, you can get the same approach with these options:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/testaddr';
$curl = curl_init();                
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

//If you need to check result, use this:
if (!curl_errno($curl)) {
  $http_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  if ($http_code === 200) {
    echo "OK";
  } else {
    echo 'Unexpected HTTP code: ', $http_code, "\n";
  }
}
curl_close($curl);
unset($result);
```

In that case it's the same, you get the response on $result var, but, you didn't use it, in that case, it isn't a security failure.

Also, in both cases, for security reasons and prevent excessive memory usage, I delete the $result variable after finish the process.

As you can see on PHP doc:

> CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER    TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the
>   return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.

Comment: What if they insert something other than a url into the function?

Comment: That's depend on the compatibility of the function. For example, if you use the correct options, you can use CURL to get a ftp file. But, in that case, the return codes can change.

Answer (score 1):

#### Two different levels

I think that you have two different levels of security here that you want to address. You may want to secure the communication channel to avoid someone spoofing the http request, and you may want to sanitize the response to avoid nasty side-effects.

#### Securing the HTTP request

This part depends largely on the destination server and how the communication is handled. If you can enforce HTTPS, then you can be pretty safe against [MITM](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks. Otherwise you're always liable to spoofing.

#### Sanitizing the response

When you get the response back to your server, it all depends on how you use that data. It doesn't have much to do with the function of choice, but rather with how you use the data after the call.
Since you allow the users to input this way, just expect the worst. At this point, the most common best practices for sanitizing input applies: use PDO for database access, escape chars with the &#xHH; format, and so on.

I hope this could answer your concerns, otherwise feel free to comment my answer!